# Do i need to know jquery to learn and work on react js / angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, reactjs

I just completed HTML, CSS & JavaScript and i think im pretty good and confident in them i want learn angular js / react js to become a Complete Front End Developer

SO

Do i need to learn JQuery before learning angular js / react js  & PLS SUGGEST me one of the framework too.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You really should not be using jQuery with React so no. It is also a personal opinion so not a good question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for React or Angular.

My advice would be to try out the starter tutorial for both react and angular, provided in their documentation and decide which you like better.

Picking up one of these libraries will not make you a complete Frontend developer. For example, a lot of jobs will want you to understand some CSS compilers like SCSS or LESS as well as some experience with build tools like Webpack.

All this will come in time. For now, have a look at the tutorials, learn something new and have some fun.

Comment: Plz tell me what all i need to learn to become complete Front End web developer

Comment: Keep going with a JS library like React or a framework like angular. Have a look at SCSS and Webpack and you'll be well on your way.

Comment: what else i need to learn?

Comment: A question like this is very opinion based and not really for stackoverflow. It would, however, be perfect on a Reddit form